# PHP Multiple File Uploader is uploading only a single file

Tags: php

I have been browsing through S.O for hours and still can't figure out why my code is not working. I am trying to upload multiple music files but for some reason only 1 file out of all selected is being uploaded.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<input id="songs" name="songs[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept=".ogg,.flac,.mp3" />
```

**PHP**

```
$path = "../songs/"; //file to place within the server
$valid_formats1 = array("mp3", "ogg", "flac"); //list of file extention to be accepted
$tot = count($_FILES['songs']['name']);

for($i = 0; $i < $tot ; $i++){
    $temporaryPathOfImage = $_FILES['songs']['tmp_name'][$i];

    if ($temporaryPathOfImage != ""){
        $dirPath = "../songs/" . $_FILES['songs']['name'][$i];

        if(move_uploaded_file($temporaryPathOfImage, $dirPath)) {
          echo "Stored in: " . "../songs/" . $_FILES['songs']['name'][$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per your other post, check Error status for each file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762378/php-filesnametype-returning-empty-value

Comment: You're assuming everything is correct every time. I'd start by inspecting `$_FILES` (use a debugger or call `var_dump($_FILES)`) and checking the `error` keys.