# PHP $_FILES['name']['type'] returning empty value

Tags: php

So I'm trying to upload multiple `mp3` files at once and only one was being uploaded. I did some tracing and it turns out that for some reason, some of the file types are returning empty values, so I think as a result they are not being uploaded. I'm not too sure though and my research hasn't yielded much because I don't know exactly what to research at this point.

Here's the array that's being returned when I upload multiple mp3 files.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => a.mp3
            [1] => e.mp3
            [2] => s.mp3
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => audio/mp3
            [2] => 
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => /private/var/tmp/phpfqxWTx
            [2] => 
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1908445
            [2] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Looks like they returned errors, so the other values (type, size) weren't set?

Comment: your file seems in error (error[0] => 1), you checked the log ?
is the file size bigger than upload_max_filesize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just didn't check the most relevant field, `error`:

> ```
> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
> ```

[Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: I feel so dumb for not looking at the obvious. Thanks a lot!